# Как избавиться от ошибки CORS в React.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors

Я подключил Firebase Auth, для входа на сайт с помощью аккаунта Google. При использовании кнопки **sign in with google** на мгновение вылезает окно входа, и закрывается. Консоль выдаёт ошибку

```
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. (Причина: заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin» не совпадает с «https://localhost:3000»).
```

Пересмотрел кучу топиков на эту тему, никак не смог разобраться что нужно сделать. Сам скрипт входа:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, браузеры запрещают `CORS` запросы с `localhost`.

Мои коллеги использовали этот npm пакет: [local-cors-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-cors-proxy). Им помогло.

Comment: В итоге решил свою проблему сам же, правда это немного странное решение, но суть в том, что я избавился от ошибки.

В браузере Firefox я установил расширение [cors-plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-plugin/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) и [Cors everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search).

Тем не менее, спасибо за решение.